# customize Y AXIS SCALE using Zed Graph

Tags: c#

I want to customize Y AXIS SCALE using Zed Graph in C#? i am using following code , but not working Properly.

```
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 500;
myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 1000;
```

Comment: We need some more code so we can figure our the problem. What were your results when you tried your solution, what did exactly fail?

Comment: i want  set scale 10000 to 100000 and minor step 10000

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to check:

1. Check the `YAxis.Scale.MinAuto` and `YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto` is set to false if you are setting programmatic scales
2. After you've set the scale call `myPane.AxisChange()` to tell it to refresh it's drawn scale